# Unresolved function when using method map()

Tags: angular, typescript, http

Unable to resolve function map(). I also tried importing rxjs/add/operator/map

```
getVenues() {
if (this.placeValue != null && this.placeValue != "" && this.recipeValue != null && this.recipeValue != "") {
  this._http.get("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search" +
    "?client_id=3PPNMTIKJJNDVYPFOBGSHHV2PR5A2P05PYHXDN2MKSKTTBSX" +
    "&client_secret=0QPHT0F5RS043F4TB4KKPQSHKSAXKE5ZNOYGB5KL2MBDYAG4" +
    "&v=20160215&limit=5" +
    "&near=" + this.placeValue +
    "&query=" + this.recipeValue)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
      // and save the data for later reference
      this.data1 = data.results[0].key;
      console.log(this.data1)},
      err => console.log(err)

      );
```

If I use HttpClientModule instead of HttpClient, I get the error

> Unable to resolve method get()

Comment: Can you provide stackBlitz for this? or you can convert that in to `promise` also

Comment: Which version of Angular do you use? If its greater than 6 then wrap your map with a pipe method, or you don't have to manually convert to json as by default you will get parsed json only.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we use `pipe()` when using `httpclient`.

```
this.http.get(url).pipe(map(a => b), catchError(error => this.handleError(error)));
```

Just as its comments of `httpClient.get()`:

> ```
> /**
>  * Construct a GET request which interprets the body as JSON and returns it.
>  *
>  * @return an `Observable` of the body as type `T`.
>  */
> ```

Since it's returning an `Obervable` then you follow the [pipe](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pipe) to merge the functions into a chain.

#### Tips

- you should use `!==` and `===` in JS to avoid weird results;
- normally we do not `subscribe` directly after the `get` and we put the get method in a separate *service*;

Comment: Got to know that `HttpClient.get()` applies res.json() automatically and returns `Observable<HttpResponse<string>>`. So, the map() can be removed. As said, if we donot `subscribe()` directly after `get`, when to do it?

Comment: Move the get methods to a service and subscribe when used in the components, it’s easier to test and manage since the components shall not consider how to get the data actually.